# Getting fixture error while using pytest-expect

Tags: python, pytest

I was reading about pytest-expect and tried the code they have given as a example

```
import pytest
def test_func(expect):
    expect('a' == 'b')
    expect(1 != 1)
    a = 1
    b = 2
    expect(a == b, 'a:%s b:%s' % (a,b))
```

on the terminal I have given command as

```
py.test test.py
```

getting error as below

```
def test_func(expect):
E       fixture 'expect' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

Do I need to defind `expect` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your error locally and then found [documentation of pytest-expect](https://pythontesting.net/pytest-expect/) from which the sample code came from.

I tried to find the source code for `pytest-expect`: what I found was [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gsnedders/pytest-expect/issues/5#issuecomment-232667661) where the author of *that* package commented "Seems that there are two different "pytest-expect" packages!" So I thought, OK, so it's just a matter of confirming that we pull the exact correct version of the package, right?

Going back to [the docs from which the code sample in the question comes from](https://pythontesting.net/pytest-expect/), down below we see a link to [pytest-expect code now in a github repo](https://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-expect-github-repo/). This repo *does* seem to contain the appropriate `expect` fixture, but the README.md indicates that "This repo is archived. Further development of this feature has moved to [pytest-check](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-check/)."

The demo code provided for pytest-check does indeed work to allow multiple "checks" to be executed in a single test.

#### Contents of test.py

```py
import pytest_check as check


def test_example():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = [2, 4, 6]
    check.greater(a, b)
    check.less_equal(b, a)
    check.is_in(a, c, "Is 1 in the list")
    check.is_not_in(b, c, "make sure 2 isn't in list")
```

#### Contents of requirements.txt

```
pytest
pytest-check
```

#### Execute test.py

First `pip install -r requirements.txt` and then run `pytest test.py`.